# Error, unmet dependencies at installation

Tags: installation-profiles

i have an error at drupal installation with **my custom profil** - version 2. i have **successfully created a custom profile** - version 1 - and installation is ok, thus i know how to do it and it works. 
Note: i am installing the Drupal files with composer.

i've tried hard without success to find a answer for my problem on the internet, essentially in those tread :

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2922417

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3045349#comment-13054710

I have this error on the last installation step "Configure site"

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException: Configuration objects provided by <em class="placeholder">bsd_showcase</em> have unmet dependencies: <em class="placeholder">block.block.about (bootstrap_for_drupal_distrib), block.block.adminimal_theme_breadcrumbs (adminimal_theme), block.block.bartik_account_menu (bartik), block.block.seven_breadcrumbs (seven)</em> in Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create() (line 98 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/UnmetDependenciesException.php).

Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create('bsd_showcase', Array) (Line: 509)
Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall('module', 'bsd_showcase') (Line: 132)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Config\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall('module', 'bsd_showcase') (Line: 161)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, ) (Line: 83)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, ) (Line: 1644)
install_install_profile(Array) (Line: 702)
install_run_task(Array, Array) (Line: 577)
install_run_tasks(Array, NULL) (Line: 117)
install_drupal(Object) (Line: 44)
```

Even if i delete the concerned config file in the above error log, new ones are named after a new installation attempt.The only difference is that version 2 have more module enabled, thus i suppose the problem come from there, do you know modules that cause problem at installation profile? Can you give me any hint, i am out of idea where to search...

Here is the list of modules of my profile.

```
name: 'bsd showcase'
type: profile
description: 'bsd showcase description'
core: 8.x
distribution:
  name: 'bsd showcase'
  langcode: en
install:
  - admin_toolbar
  - admin_toolbar_tools
  - adminimal_admin_toolbar
  - allowed_formats
  - autogrow
  - automated_cron
  - backup_migrate
  - big_pipe
  - block
  - block_content
  - book
  - breakpoint
  - ckeditor
  - ckeditor_abbreviation
  - ckeditor_codemirror
  - ckeditor_details
  - ckeditor_iframe
  - ckeditor_quote
  - ckeditor_specialchars
  - ckeditor_templates
  - ckeditor_templates_ui
  - ckwordcount
  - color
  - colorbutton
  - comment
  - config
  - contact
  - content_moderation
  - contextual
  - crop
  - ctools
  - datetime
  - dblog
  - default_content
  - default_content_set
  - devel
  - devel_generate
  - diff
  - dynamic_page_cache
  - editor
  - entity_reference_revisions
  - fakeobjects
  - feeds
  - field
  - field_ui
  - file
  - filter
  - focal_point
  - form_placeholder
  - hal
  - help
  - history
  - honeypot
  - image
  - layout_builder
  - layout_discovery
  - link
  - linkit
  - matomo
  - media
  - media_library
  - menu_ui
  - metatag
  - metatag_facebook
  - metatag_open_graph
  - metatag_twitter_cards
  - nbsp
  - node
  - notification
  - options
  - page_cache
  - panelbutton
  - path
  - path_alias
  - quickedit
  - rdf
  - redirect_after_login
  - responsive_image
  - search
  - serialization
  - settings_tray
  - shortcut
  - statistics
  - syslog
  - system
  - taxonomy
  - telephone
  - text
  - token
  - toolbar
  - tour
  - tracker
  - update
  - user
  - video_embed_field
  - views_bulk_operations
  - views_infinite_scroll
  - views_ui
  - workflows
  - forum
  - menu_link_content
  - pathauto
  - views
  - paragraphs
theme:
  - stable
  - classy
  - bartik
  - seven
  - adminimal_theme
  - bootstrap_for_drupal_distrib
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You asked: > Can you give me any hint, i am out of idea where to search... Your error message lists some line numbers. Have you tried setting an XDebug breakpoint at one of those lines and examining the code there? You can use XDebug to inspect the values of local variables to see what it is that Drupal does not like about your installation profile. That would be my best advice.

Comment: `Even if i delete the concerned config file` I wonder what file you are deleting? The installer appears to be missing the indicated `block.*` config files. To overcome this you should add some files I think. (Or remove references to these files from other configs.)

Comment: The name of the below files are written in the error message and are config file of the profile : block.block.about, 
block.block.adminimal_theme_breadcrumbs, 
block.block.bartik_account_menu, 
block.block.seven_breadcrumbs. And those are very basic config file and should not cause problems.

Comment: No, I never used Xdebug. i suppose i will have to dig that deeply if no one help me with this. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: *block.block.adminimal_theme_breadcrumbs (adminimal_theme)* should be interpreted as block.block.adminimal_theme_breadcrumbs having a dependency from adminimal_theme, which is missing.

Comment: How should i understand "dependency",  for example that the theme/module adminimal_theme is not present? adminimal_theme is of course installed? that's why i don't understand those errors, i think it's the discovery of those dependency that doesn't work. very odd.